# 400 Bad request error Python, Flask, SQLite

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I am attempting to do the backend for a simple website which connect to a db file called mydatabase1.1.db. The KeyError:'title' but everything is working fine with that variable so I am completely baffled.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/">
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title">
        <br>
        <label for="content">Content:</label>
        <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Post!">
      </form>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import sqlite3
from datetime import date

app = Flask(__name__)


# Route that accepts form data and updates the database
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_database():
    # Get the form data
    conn = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase1.1.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    # Get the highest postID value from the post_table
    c.execute('SELECT MAX(postID) FROM post_table')
    result = c.fetchone()
    if result[0] is None:
        postID = 1
    else:
        postID = result[0] + 1
    #authorID is 1 because I have not made profile DB yet.
    authorID = 1
    title = request.form['title']
    content = request.form['content']
    dateOfPost = date.today()

        print(postID, authorID, title, content, dateOfPost)
    
    # Validate the form data
    if not title or not content:
        return 'Error: Please fill in all required fields'

    # Create the post_table if doesn't exist
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_table (
             postID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
             authorID INTEGER,
             title TEXT,
             content TEXT,
             dateOfPost TEXT)''')

    # Insert the data into the database
    c.execute('INSERT INTO post_table (postID, authorID, title, content, dateOfPost) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (postID, authorID, title, content, dateOfPost))
    conn.commit()

    # Close the database connection
    conn.close()
    
    # Redirect the user to a confirmation page
    return 'Post created successfully'
#debug on to see errors clearer
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `title = request.form['title']` This line of code only makes sense if it's a POST request.  If it's a GET request, then no form was submitted.  Your view should not try to process the form input on a GET request, because there isn't any.